# Pyramids route_url with additional query arguments

Tags: python, url-routing, pyramid

In Pyramids framework, functions `route_path` and `route_url` are used to generate urls from routes configuration. So, if I have route:

```
config.add_route('idea', 'ideas/{idea}')
```

I am able to generate the url for it using

```
request.route_url('idea', idea="great");
```

However, sometimes I may want to add additional get parameters to generate url like:

```
idea/great?sort=asc
```

How to do this?

I have tried

```
request.route_url('idea', idea='great', sort='asc')
```

But that didn't work.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can add additional query arguments to url passing the `_query` dictionary

```
request.route_url('idea', idea='great', _query={'sort':'asc'})
```

Comment: if you're answering your own question you have no excuse to not accept it ;-)

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Mako templates, `_query={...}` won't work; instead you need to do:

```
${request.route_url('idea', idea='great', _query=(('sort', 'asc'),))}
```

The tuple of 2-tuples works as a dictionary.

Comment: I'm using mako and _query { ... } worked just fine, perhaps you can tell us why it won't work?

Comment: @SSIgnatzSchönborn: Did you enclose your `_query { ... }` with `${}`? It seemed that Mako templates would not do nested braces. Perhaps a new version has remedied that? I could try a repro if necessary, although I haven't touched Mako in a while.