# Redirect via HTTPFound parameters not being passed

Tags: redirect, pyramid

I have a Pyramid app using URL disptach. I have a route '/delete' that removes a record from the database and redirects to a view. When the redirect happens, I want the view to reload on the same page. I'm using webhelpers.paginate for pagination. The problem is, when the redirection happens, the parameters are not passed.

The delete route:

```
@view_config(route_name='delete')
def delete(request):
    # Get the current page, the page title, and the id of the record to delete
    current_page = int(request.params.get('page', 1))

    # Database transactions
    ...
    # Reload the view
    url = request.route_url(route_name='records', app_name='BLAH', userid='BLAH', page=current_page)
    return HTTPFound(location=url)
```

The records view:

```
@view_config(route_name='records', renderer='records.jinja2')
def records(request):
    # Get the current page
    current_page = int(request.params.get('page', 1))
```

When the records view is loaded, the parameters are not passed and the default value of '1' is set for the current_page. The values of "BLAH" for the app_name and user_id aren't passed either.

One thing I did notice is that it seems like the view is loaded twice but I don't know how to confirm that. I think the page is loaded twice because I see two calls to the database after the redirect.

What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: Look in the developer tools of your browser to see the requests happening. In Chrome, you can "Preserve Log upon Navigation", if that helps. Also, you could add `print('stuff')` in both view functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the url when your `print url` in delete route and what it the route `records` definition?
If your want a GET [Request](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/request.html?highlight=route_url#pyramid.request.Request.route_url), you shoud try keyword argument `_query`

```
url = request.route_url(name='records', _query=(('page', current_page),))
```

Comment: Also, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11989317/pyramids-route-url-with-additional-query-arguments